# setting checkbox Checked in user_registration_form

Tags: forms

```
Array
(
[account]
   [notify] => Array
                (
                    [#type] => checkbox
                    [#title] => Notify user of new account
                    [#access] => 1
                )

)
```

I want to checkbox on user_registration_form must be checked by default.
I did `$form['account']['notify']['#default_value'] = array(1);` but it does't work.Suggest something.

Comment: Have you tried this $form['account']['notify']['#default_value'] = TRUE;

Comment: @Vamsi consider adding your suggestion as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this

```
$form['account']['notify']['#default_value'] = TRUE;
```

Thank You.

Comment: its done ...working fine...